# How to force Tomcat to delete expired Sessions when loggin User closes his Browser?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security, tomcat7, session-timeout

I implemented a SessionListener to track the open sessions of my webserver

I set in my `web.xml`:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>demo.MyHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

My demo.MyHttpSessionListener.groovy:

```
class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
   @Override
   public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    ...
   }

     @Override
     public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
       ...
     }
}
```

When I go to my website **sessionCreated** is called. **sessionDestroyed** is called when I close my browser an wait for the session timeout.

The problem occurs when I loggin on my website and close my browser. In this case **sessionDestroyed** is never called after the timeout. Why will a session never be deleted when a user has been logged in and closes the browser?
What do I have to do to get the expired sessions of a logged in user deleted after he closes his browser and waits the time out time?

Comment: You cannot do anything in the event of a user closing their browser. The session will timeout on its own when `<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>` minute has passed since the last session interaction.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know, but after a while the timeout should be processed. The sessionDestroyed is never called when you where logged in before, close the browser and wait the timeout minutes. sessionDestroyed is only called on sessions where no loggin was performed.

Comment: Check BalusC's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945582/how-to-call-sessiondestroyed-when-a-session-times-out). It seems that although the session might be invalidated after a minute, the container won't call `sessionDestroyed()` until some implementation specific time interval.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis **sessionDestroyed** is called after the timeout interval correctly if I haven't been logged in before. On sessions without login it works fine.

Comment: Go in debug mode, login, check the debugger id for the session object. The close your browser or whatever you did before. Wait a few minutes and log back in. Compare the id you get this time with the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Even if you set session timeout in your web.xml, Spring Security will override this value when a user is logged in. The timeout is set to:

```
session.maxInactiveInterval = -1
```

So you have to override this value again in order to make session timeout working.