# Destroying session in servlets

Tags: java, session, servlets

I know that when a session is invalidated explicitaly, you can do some extra stuff in the method sessionDestroyed() from a HttpSessionListener Servlet, like printing a message or anything else.

My questions are:

1. If you have the browser opened, but you are not doing anything so your session expires... will be the method sessionDestroyed() called?
2. If you close your browser and the session expires because you were out for too long... will be the method sessionDestroyed() called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To both questions the answer is: yes.

The server cannot distinguish between the two scenarios (assuming the webpage doesn't call the server on his own via Ajax). The servlet server only knows the time of the last call for that session and triggers the session destruction after time out.

You can try it yourself. Set the session timeout to a small value and wait.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpSessionListener` is used to monitor when sessions are created and destroyed on the app server

`public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent evt)`is a notification that a session is about to be invalidated.

For more information [How to call sessionDestroyed when a session times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945582/how-to-call-sessiondestroyed-when-a-session-times-out)